# Issues with my Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I was trying to build a simple maven project but ran into some difficulty. I was checking out the instructions from this site-> http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/

but when I took a look at the structure, I discovered in my project structure, I couldn't find the `.project` and the `.classpath`  files. I only found the `pom.xml`. When I ran the project, I hit an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/henry/directory/App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.henry.directory.App
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.henry.directory</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FirstMaven</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I hope someone could help me out at why the class could not be found.

Comment: Maven is used to **build** an app. .classpath and .project files have nothing to do with Maven. They're eclipse files. You have a problem when **running** the app. How do you run it?

Comment: well, from eclipse, I just clicked the green run bottom.I mean by running the App.java

Comment: So did you use the m2e ecxlipse plugin to import the Maven project into Eclipse? Have you compiled the project? Edit your question, and precisely describe the steps you have followed to buid and run the app.

Comment: Go inside your maven project directory and type `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. This will generate a project.

Comment: Also, to be sure, is com/henry/* a child of {projectRoot}/src/main/java?

Comment: @Bart Not a good idea if the OP is using the m2e plugin.

Comment: If this is a new project, you should use the latest versions of your libs. Also you normally don't need to specify the dependencies of Hibernate explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies, the problem was the hibernate artifactId was not correct. For some reasons, I do not know but that is what I am currently investigating..